# How to reset a checkbox value

Tags: c#

I have a form which display's to checkboxes and they are empty.

When I select one of them I want to check if the other was already selected and if so I want to turnoff the checkmark.

I tried this code:

```
private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inactive_checkbox.Checked)
        inactive_checkbox.Checked = false;
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (active_checkbox.Checked)
        active_checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

But when I select Inactive and Active was already selected, the checkmark is gone from both checkboxes.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - Also: The events are called whenever the Checked property changes so you need to add code to tell the difference if the reason is your code or the user..

Comment: might i suggest a radio button?

Comment: You can simply the logic via: 
inactive_checkbox.Checked = !active_checkbox.Checked; etc.

Comment: One way you can do this is to use `RadioButton`s instead of `CheckBox`es. This will ensure that only one option is selected at a time.

Comment: Hi TaW is Winforms. I am new on this, I will tag it as Winforms next time.

Comment: I am using Checkbox Daniel A. White because the user defined it as a Checkbox, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the checkbox the following things happen:

1. The CheckedChanged for that checkbox triggers
2. It unchecks the other checkbox
3. The CheckedChanged for the other checkbox triggers
4. That one unchecks the first checkbox.

You need to check whether the change is caused by code or user input. This is one way to do it:

```
bool codeChecking;

private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (codeChecking)
        return;

    try  
    {
        codeChecking = true;
        if (inactive_checkbox.Checked)
            inactive_checkbox.Checked = false;
    }
    finally 
    {
        codeChecking = false;
    }
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (codeChecking)
        return;         

    try  
    {
        codeChecking = true;
        if (active_checkbox.Checked)
            active_checkbox.Checked = false;
    }
    finally 
    {
        codeChecking = false;
    }       
}
```

I put `try..finally` in there because in the case where an exception is thrown by a handler, if the `codeChecking = false` is not in a finally block it will leave your application in a state where it is impossible to check either checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

> When I select one of them I want to check if the other was already selected and if so I want to turnoff the checkmark

It seems unobvious whether you want to turn off the checkmark from the checkbox you've just checked or from the another one. Since I don't have enough reputation yet to ask for clarification in comments, I'll provide both solutions.

If you want to uncheck another checkbox (which make more sense to me), this code should do the trick:

```
private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (active_checkbox.Checked)
        inactive_checkbox.Checked = false;
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inactive_checkbox.Checked)
        active_checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

And if you want to uncheck the checkbox you've just checked...

```
private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inactive_checkbox.Checked)
        active_checkbox.Checked=false;
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (active_checkbox.Checked)
        inactive_checkbox.Checked=false;
}
```

This should do the trick. But may I suggest simply **disabling** another checkbox while another one is checked? This should help to avoid confusing the user:

```
private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    inactive_checkbox.Enabled=!active_checkbox.Checked;
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    active_checkbox.Enabled=!inactive_checkbox.Checked;
}
```

All three solutions are simple, scalable, do not create any additional global variables and are able to use the advantage of checkboxes over radiobuttons - ability to leave them both unchecked.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was only slightly wrong. You needed this:

```
private void active_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (active_checkbox.Checked)
        inactive_checkbox.Checked = false;
}

private void inactive_checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inactive_checkbox.Checked)
        active_checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

You just need to check if the currently changing check box is selected the deselect the other one. Simple.