# ASP.net How to reverse specific CheckBox visually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, checkbox, event-handling

**Goal**: User toggles a checkbox, and then a modal pops up to confirm either Yes(update DB), or No (undo selection).
I want to have checkbox reverse user selection IF they click the No button in the confirmation dialog.
For example: If they click to toggle On, but when the confirmation comes they click No, it should toggle back to Off

**Problem/What's happening:** When I debug, it says the value is being reversed, however on the page I can see nothing has visually happened

**What I've tried:** I tried with conditional, setting the checkboxvariable.Checked = true or false accordingly. But it doesn't change anything on screen.
Ive used the debugger to watch values while doing this
I've tried setting it simply with no conditions, and also tried it with different conditions.
[How to reset a checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816914/how-to-reset-a-checkbox-value)

**C#**:

```
//Checkbox event
 protected void cbUpdateAvailability_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        CheckBox cbSender = (CheckBox)sender;
        providerIndex = getProviderIndexCB(cbSender.ClientID);//int providerIndex = getProviderIndexCB(cbSender.ClientID);
        
        Session["providerIndex"] = providerIndex;
        availableTxt.Text = (cbSender.Checked) ? "available" : "unavailable";
        DrName.Text = providerStatsListDto.ProviderStatsList[providerIndex].LastName;
        
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "availabilityModal", "$('#availabilityModal').modal();", true);
        upModal.Update();
 }
    
//Confirmation Button click event
protected void btnUpdateAvailability_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
    if (btnSender.Text == "Yes") {
        //Update DB
    }
    else
    {
        //If they click No , flip checkbox back
        //Session variable to know which checkbox?
        //chkOnOff2.Checked = (chkOnOff2.Checked) ? false : true; //even when Checked becomes false, it doesn't visually change, why?
        //chkOnOff2.Checked = (availableTxt.Text == "available") ? false :  true;
       //chkOnOff2.Enabled = false;
       // chkOnOff2.Enabled = (availableTxt.Text == "available") ? false : true; 
      //chkOnOff2.Checked = (chkOnOff2.Checked) ? false : true;
      //chkOnOff2.Checked = (availableTxt.Text == "available") ? false :  true;
    }
```

**ASPX**:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="margin-center">
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateAvailability" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="btn btn-green" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnUpdateAvailability_Click"/>

        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateAvailabilityNo" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" ClientIDMode="Static"  OnClick="btnUpdateAvailability_Click"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you change the checkbox state in code the event will run and undo the change.  You have to disable the event before changing in code and then renable.  Use : chkOnOff2.Enabled = false;

Comment: @jdweng Thank you. I just tried this and a few variations, using .Enabled did not seem to make any difference

Comment: Are you getting into the click event?  Add break point.

Comment: Yes, I added your suggestion into the else block above which is inside a click event. I put breakpoints at and after the line(s) and it shows that .Enabled gets updated/set, but nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: Check the sender.  It looks like you have more than one checkbox.  The names may be wrong.  You can right click the text box in the designer and select properties.  The check first row of properties for the name of the checkbox.

Comment: I took another look. The sender when clicking the No button is "btnUpdateAvailabilityNo" , which makes sense because I am clicking the No button for the confirmation dialog event. The Checkbox event happens *before* the confirmation dialog event. As far as the checkboxes, yes I have multiple, but for now I am just trying to get it to work for chkOnOff2, and I am only clicking the second Checkbox to make sure it matches. When the Checkbox event fires, the sender is chkOnOff2.

Comment: It looks like the page does a Postback when clicking the CheckBox, but not when clicking the Button. I wonder if that has something to do with it. Not sure why, I have AutoPostBack="true" and runat="server" on the aspx element. But it does update the Database when they click the Yes button, just nothing happens when they click the No button

Comment: You need to register the No button with a +=.  You can register from the designer page from window where the properties are located.  You can open the deisgner.cs file to see how properties values are set.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the +=. the No button exists in the designer file:         protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnUpdateAvailabilityNo;
 -- I added some of my aspx code to this post (the part with the Yes and No buttons).

Comment: You have to open the plus signs in the designer file to see the properties.